# Assign (endless) output of a program to a variable using a MS batch

Tags: batch-file, variables, output

I need to process the endless output of a program with a MS batch file. It can be useful to break each line and process it. The problem is that every code I tried first waits for the program to finish and then run.

My program output is similar to this:

```
ping -t 8.8.8.8
```

And the ouput is similar to this:

```
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=27ms TTL=117
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=207ms TTL=117
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=18ms TTL=117
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=18ms TTL=117
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=23ms TTL=117
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=15ms TTL=117
...
```

Note: the program I am using is nc.exe, listening to a udp port with endless output to the console.

Comment: I am not quite getting the question, please can you edit your question and clarify.

Comment: i guess you need piping, something like [tee.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=32615#p32615)